# How to convert FormData into Object then JSON.stringify that?

Tags: json, reactjs, form-data, stringify

How would I convert my FormData into an object than JSON.stringify that? I think a reason why my values in the API are not being populated with my data is because endpoint expects JSON data.

handleSubmit:

```
handleSubmit(event) {
      event.preventDefault();

      const data = new FormData(event.target);

      fetch('http://localhost:8080/seniorproject/addUser', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: data,
      });

      console.log(data);
    }
```

Form:

```
<form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <label htmlFor="First Name">Enter First Name</label>
          <input id="firstName" name="firstName" type="text" />

          <label htmlFor="Last Name">Enter your Last Name</label>
          <input id="lastName" name="lastName" type="lastName" />

          <label htmlFor="studentID">Enter your student id</label>
          <input id="studentID" name="studentID" type="text" />

          <label htmlFor="Email">Enter your email</label>
          <input id="email" name="email" type="text" />

          <label htmlFor="Password">Enter your password</label>
          <input id="password" name="password" type="text" />

          <button>Send data!</button>
        </form>
```

Comment: may i know if u r importing redux-form ?

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [`formData.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/entries) method to loop over all the entries in the `FormData` and construct a JSON object, like so:

```
const json = {};
Array.from(formData.entries()).forEach(([key, value]) => {
  json[key] = value;
})

JSON.stringify(json)
```